# How to tell Java SAX Parser to ignore invalid character references?

Tags: java, xml, error-handling, sax

When trying to parse incorrect XML with a character reference such as `&#x1`, Java's SAX Parser dies a horrible death with a fatal error such as

```
    org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Character reference "&#x1"
                                   is an invalid XML character.
```

Is there any way around this? Will I have to clean up the XML file before I hand it off to the SAX Parser? If so, is there an elegant way of going about this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use XML 1.1! skaffman is completely right, but you can just stick `<?xml version="1.1"?>` on the top of your files and you'll be in good shape. If you're dealing with streams, write a wrapper that rewrites or adds that processing instruction.

Comment: wow, it works. are there downsides or compatibility issues with using xml 1.1?

Comment: check out the "Rationale and list of changes for XML 1.1" at http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-xml11

If I recall correctly, any valid xml 1.0 document is a valid in xml 1.1

Comment: since this keeps coming in handy for people, a great shortcut to add this header is:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PushbackInputStream.html#unread(byte[])

Answer (score 7):

You're going to have to clean up your XML, I'm afraid. Such characters are invalid according to the XML spec, and no amount of persuasion is going to convince the parser otherwise.

[Valid XML characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Details_on_valid_characters) for XML 1.0:

- `U+0009`
- `U+000A`
- `U+000D`
- `U+0020` – `U+D7FF`
- `U+E000` – `U+FFFD`
- `U+10000` – `U+10FFFF`

In order to clean up, you'll have to pass the data through a more low-level processor, which treats it as a unicode character stream, removing those characters that are invalid.

Comment: only problem is i'd have to be doing the decoding of the character entities myself... bummer.

Answer (score 3):

This is invalid XML so no parser should parse it without error.

But you do encounter such hand-crafted invalid XML in real world. My solution is to manually insert [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) markers to the data. For example,

```
  <data><![CDATA[ garbage with &invalid characters ]]></data>
```

Of course, you will get the data back as is and you have to deal with the invalid characters yourself.

Comment: Nope. Invalid characters are still invalid inside CDATA sections.

Comment: Please check the fact before you downvote. The character reference inside CDATA is treated as regular string. Even though "&#x1" represents a invalid reference but it's made of all valid characters. I do this all the time with several parsers so I know I am correct.