# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Character reference "&#x0" is an invalid XML character

Tags: c#, java, .net

I am sending a string from .net service to java class but in java , I am getting  **org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Character reference "&#x0" is an invalid XML character.**

Please help me in solving this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What encoding does the document use, and does it declare it? What *is* the content of the string? Are you deliberately trying to include U+0000?

Answer (score 1):

In C or C++ strings are terminated by the `null` (or '\0'). In C# a string can contain a `null`, but often these come from a C/C++ function.

You can get rid of the `null` in the .net String with

```
s = s.Replace("\0", "");  // just removes the null
```

or

```
int pos = s.IndexOf('\0');  
if (pos >= 0)
    s = s.Substring(0, pos); // removes the null and the rest of the string
```

depending on what is the reason for the `null` in the string.

Comment: Hi Roland, Thanks for your reply. I have removed null character from the string but output is not stable. I am getting illegal argument exception some times and sometimes I am getting correct output. Please help me in solving this.

Comment: @sulthana Can you give some more information in which circumstances the exception occures and when does it work? And where the exception occures (java or .net part, which line/command )...

Comment: hi Roland, The exception is coming in java.While returning the string in JAVA class the exception is coming.  Here is the exception **SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet AppService threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The char '0x0' after 'return    ' is not a valid XML character.

Comment: looks like there is still a '\0' in one of the arguments. can you asure that there are no more '\0' in all of the arguments?

Comment: @sulthana is this question related to the other questions [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861597/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-is-not-a-valid-xml-character) from you? Then you should first solve the connection/proxy problem, as this has nothing to do with passing back a string from .net.

Comment: Hi, Please try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997255/how-to-tell-java-sax-parser-to-ignore-invalid-character-references) solution.

Answer (score 0):

Some invalid characters will cause Exception while parsing XML, official defined those three scopes of invalid characters:

```
0x00 - 0x08  
0x0b - 0x0c  
0x0e - 0x1f
```

So you may filter them before parsing XML content.